# Multiple OR operators in ternary condition,

Tags: javascript, operator-precedence, conditional-operator, or-operator

I'm trying to create a new string by checking the value of a character and replacing it based on the true or false evaluation from the ternary operator.

I have had success using only a single character and from what I have read it is possible to have a ternary operator condition include the || or operator. I have tried using only two and it's not producing the correct result.

Is it because once the condition is met is wont go past || or operator?

How much can ternary conditions contain and would it work better to put conditions into a variable or function?

I'm aware the problem can be solved differently but I am experimenting with the ternary operator to gain a better understanding.

Thanks in advance, I'm new to JavsScript.

.

```js
let input = 'President Donald Trump signed an executive order on Friday aimed at preventing counterfeit products from abroad from being sold to U.S. citizens who shop online using Amazon.com, Walmart.com or other e-commerce websites, the White House said.'


const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
const ranNum = () => {return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)}

let news = ''

const swapper = input => {
  let count = 0
    while (count != input.length) {
      let cond = input[count].toLowerCase()
      cond != ' ' || cond != 'a' ? news += vowels[ranNum()] : news += input[count]
    count ++
  } console.log(news)
}



console.log(input)
swapper(input)

//c != 'a' || c != 'e' || c != 'i' || c != 'o' || c != 'u'
```

Comment: You can't use ternary like that. It is now working as short circuit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is

```
cond != ' ' || cond != 'a' ? (...)
```

This condition will *always* be true - if `cond` is a space, it will fulfill `cond != 'a'`. If `cond` is `'a'`, it will fulfill `cond != ' '`. If `cond` is anything else, it will fulfill `cond != ' '`.

Instead use:

```
(cond === ' ' || cond === 'a') ? news += input[count] : news += vowels[ranNum()];
```

```js
let input = 'President Donald Trump signed an executive order on Friday aimed at preventing counterfeit products from abroad from being sold to U.S. citizens who shop online using Amazon.com , Walmart.com or other ecommerce websites, the White House said.'


const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
const ranNum = () => {return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)}

let news = ''

const swapper = input => {
  let count = 0
    while (count != input.length) {
      let cond = input[count].toLowerCase();
      (cond === ' ' || cond === 'a') ? news += input[count] : news += vowels[ranNum()];
    count ++
  } console.log(news)
}



console.log(input)
swapper(input)

//c != 'a' || c != 'e' || c != 'i' || c != 'o' || c != 'u'
```

That said, you *really really* shouldn't abuse the conditional operator as a replacement for `if`-`else`:

```js
let input = 'President Donald Trump signed an executive order on Friday aimed at preventing counterfeit products from abroad from being sold to U.S. citizens who shop online using Amazon.com , Walmart.com or other ecommerce websites, the White House said.'


const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
const ranNum = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
}

let news = ''

const swapper = input => {
  let count = 0
  while (count != input.length) {
    let cond = input[count].toLowerCase();
    if (cond === ' ' || cond === 'a') {
      news += input[count]
    } else {
      news += vowels[ranNum()];
    }
    count++
  }
  console.log(news)
}



console.log(input)
swapper(input)
```

If you want to use the conditional operator here, you should do it *after* the `news +=` part:

```
news += (cond === ' ' || cond === 'a') ? input[count] : vowels[ranNum()];
```

```js
let input = 'President Donald Trump signed an executive order on Friday aimed at preventing counterfeit products from abroad from being sold to U.S. citizens who shop online using Amazon.com , Walmart.com or other ecommerce websites, the White House said.'


const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
const ranNum = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
}

let news = ''

const swapper = input => {
  let count = 0
  while (count != input.length) {
    let cond = input[count].toLowerCase();
    news += (cond === ' ' || cond === 'a') ? input[count] : vowels[ranNum()];
    count++
  }
  console.log(news)
}



console.log(input)
swapper(input)
```

It might be clearer to use an array when there are multiple values to check (especially if you plan on having more than 2 checks eventually):

```js
let input = 'President Donald Trump signed an executive order on Friday aimed at preventing counterfeit products from abroad from being sold to U.S. citizens who shop online using Amazon.com , Walmart.com or other ecommerce websites, the White House said.'


const vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
const ranNum = () => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)
}

let news = ''

const swapper = input => {
  let count = 0
  while (count != input.length) {
    let cond = input[count].toLowerCase();
    news += [' ', 'a'].includes(cond) ? input[count] : vowels[ranNum()];
    count++
  }
  console.log(news)
}



console.log(input)
swapper(input)
```

Comment: When comparing to more than one value, I've grown to use this "pattern": `news += ([' ', 'a'].includes(cond)) ? input[count] : vowels[ranNum()];`. Makes it more readable, easy to add/remove comparison values and more concise on top of that. In case of simple letters you can ofc also use a string instead of an array: `news += (' a'.includes(cond)) ? input[count] : vowels[ranNum()];`